# How to completely delete a wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I created a network from hostel WiFi using the router pin number. Creating a private network is not allowed in my hostel. I have to remove the network, using the manage wireless networks option I can delete the WiFi network from my laptop but it appears in other laptops. What should I do?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Which version/SKU??

Comment: What does the SKU of the operating system have anything to do with the solution.  The solution for a given version would be universal among ALL the SKU for that version.

Answer (score 3):

Other than deleting the WiFi network from *all* computers manually, there's no way to do so.

The network details are stored in an [XML file on each computer](https://superuser.com/questions/148139/where-does-vista-windows-7-store-wireless-connection-information) and there's no way to do a "broadcast delete" of the files. Unless you write a script which goes connects to each computer & then deletes the files - which makes it sound more like a malicious file.