# How to change saved wifi password in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

Recently I changed my wifi password ( through router ).  But on my laptop ( windows 7 ) it still remembers old wifi password. It always try to connect using old password and shows Limited Access.

I tried changing it several times: ( see following snapshots )

**Step 1.**

[image]

**Step 2.**

[image]

Now at second step I change the password to correct one, and I get connected to internet. It works fine till I restart the laptop. Once restarted again same thing happens, it try to connect with old password.

I have also tried deleting the stored wifi adapter.

**Step 1.**
[image]

**Step 2.**
[image]

But it comes back again after restarting.  Please help.

**EDIT**

Just now I used `WirelessKeyView` and it shows the old password of my wifi. That means it is somewhere stored. How to delete/change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does Vista/Windows 7 store Wireless Connection Information?](http://superuser.com/questions/148139/where-does-vista-windows-7-store-wireless-connection-information)

Comment: Well what is your wireless card on your pc?

Comment: @Raystafarian and no it's not the same thing

Comment: @idavid Wireless card? You mean this:  `Broadcom netlink(TM) Gigabit ethernet` or may be this one `Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000`.  I got these in Device Manager.  By the way, my laptop is Lenovo Y470. Wireless card or anything is not changed yet.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal Well i am not sure if you got the Intel software installed but if you have it that might been restoring the pass. like Intel software it self trying to manage the wireless networks

Comment: @idavid I have it installed. Let me remove that.

Answer (score 1):

As iDavid suggested, this problem was because of Intel software. Instead of uninstalling it I simply deleted my wifi entry from this software, and Now it is working fine.

Comment: i am happy that helped you but if you where going to use only the intle's wifi software that also might work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a TrendNet wifi card in a desktop.  The TrendNet software was saving a profile for the Wifi network that it was passing along to Windows 7, along with an out-dated password.

Once I removed the Wifi network's profile in the TrendNet software and then re-joined the Wifi network through the Windows 7 interface the new password was used from that point on.